Showing $\frac{1}{(a+1)(b+1)}+\frac{1}{(a-2)(b-2)}+\frac{1}{(a-3)(b-3)}=0$, where $a$, $b$ are the roots of $(x-2)(x-3)+(x-3)(x+1)+(x+1)(x-2)=0$

If $a,b$ are the roots of
$$(x-2)(x-3)+(x-3)(x+1)+(x+1)(x-2)=0$$
then how to show the following?
$$\frac{1}{(a+1)(b+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(a-2)(b-2)}+\dfrac{1}{(a-3)(b-3)}=0$$

Substituting $x=a$ and $x=b$ respectively in the polynomial equation, I can clearly see
$$\dfrac{1}{a+1}+\dfrac{1}{a-2}+\dfrac{1}{a-3}=0=\dfrac{1}{b+1}+\dfrac{1}{b-2}+\dfrac{1}{b-3}$$ but then I am stuck.
Please help.

Note that
$$
0=(x-2)(x-3)+(x-3)(x+1)+(x+1)(x-2)=3x^2-8x+1
$$
has the roots $r=\frac{\sqrt{13}+4}{3}$ and $s=\frac{-\sqrt{13}+4}{3}$. Then the claim follows directly.

Letting $$f(x)=(x-2)(x-3)+(x-3)(x+1)+(x-2)(x+1),$$ then $f(x)=3(x-a)(x-b).$ Then $\frac1{(a-x)(b-x)}=\frac{3}{f(x)}.$ And it is easy to compute $f(-1), f(2), f(3).$
You get:
$$\frac3{f(-1)}+\frac3{f(2)}+\frac3{f(3)}=\frac3{12}+\frac3{-3}+\frac3{4}=0.$$

This works more generally, if $u,v,w$ are distinct and $a,b$ are the roots of $(x-v)(x-w)+(x-u)(x-w)+(x-u)(x-v),$ then: $$\frac{1}{(a-u)(b-u)}+\frac1{(a-v)(b-v)}+\frac1{(a-w)(b-w)}=0.$$
I wonder what happens with more than $3$ terms.
If $r_1,r_2,\dots, r_n$ are distinct real numbers, and $g(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$ and $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ are the roots of $g'(x),$ then can we say:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{g'(r_k)}=0?$$
A quick check for $n=4$ works, but the cancellation that results in $0$ is much harder.
